# Get iteration variable from js file

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have to loop over Array of objects consist of `[{ title: '', desc: '', svg: '' }, ...]`. As SVG code is too large and I don't want to clutter my `.pug` file with lots of SVG codes.

Is there anything by which I can import this Array from another JS file and just use it without outputting/generating array in it to compiled html just like a normal inlie JS in PUG:

```
someMagicImport data.js

each feature in data.features
  li= feature.title
```

data file: `data.js`

```js
const features = [
 { title: '...', desc: '...', svg: '...' },
 // .... other objects
]
```

So, the simple question is how can I use the above features array defined in `data.js` and use it in my `.pug` file for iteration.

Regards.

Update 1: More detailed question.
Update 2: I am not using any backend framework like expressJS or Django. I am just generating HTML markup from PUG.

Comment: You can require your data in node and then pass it to Pug as a local variable

Comment: If you can provide a code snippet then it will be very helpful. @Sean

Thanks.

Comment: How are you compiling Pug—with ExpressJS, Gulp, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now knowing that you're just using PugJS, you can approach it this way. Create a new pug file with an [unbuffered code block](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code), declare a variable with your data object, and then [`include`](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) that file wherever you need it.

**features.pug**

```
-
  const features = [
    { title: '...', desc: '...', svg: '...' },
    // .... other objects
  ]
```

**index.pug** (now you can access the features object)

```
include features

ul 
  each feature in features
    li= feature.title
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explained it properly. I have array of object in another file (data.js) and I want to loop over that object in my `.pug` file.

I tried your solution of `include` but it includes the js file as plain text and not like pug's JS.

Regards.

Comment: @JDSolanki How are you compiling Pug—with ExpressJS, Gulp, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for providing a full example. I really appreciate your assistance. However, I am using just simple HTML without any backend server like expressJS.

I am just generating HTML markup using PUG.

So, your example is correct but I am trying to achieve this in PUG alone without adding it to global variables like we do in frameworks like expressJS. I want that Array just like a normal JS express we write `- var someVar = 'admin'` but from another file.

Comment: I've updated my answer again @JDSolanki. Please be sure to accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much. This resolves the questions :)